# Post Video on Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I am working on the app where I need to post the image/video on instagram. I have successfully able to post the image on Instagram with following code:

```
        NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myimage.igo"];
        NSString* savePath = [imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
        {
            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
            self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.image";
            self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
            [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
```

But didn't find any way to post the video on it. I checked the Instagram app and found that we can post/upload video too. It means via code It should be possible. Is anyone know about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to post video on instagram 
it works for me hope it works for you also

first you have to save Video To Cameraroll then use this

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",yourfilepath,yourCaption];
NSString* webStringURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL* instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After the deprecation of ALAssetLibrary, Instagram has also disabled the AssetPath parameter.
You can now use the localIndentifier property of PHAsset localIndentifier for this case.

```
   NSURL *instagramURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@", placeholderForCreatedAsset.localIdentifier]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
        }
```

PS: this works fine for me but it is still not documented anywhere.